# How to find something that has been moved through several files

Tags: git, git-log

I am looking for the commit that introduced `Hello world` into by codebase. `git log -S"Hello world"` is too slow due to the size of my codebase. Instead, as I know that this is in c.txt, I use `git log -S"Hello world" -- c.txt`. It turns out that this was actually moved from b.txt in a commit. So I do `git log -S"Hello world" -- b.txt`. Now I discover that it has been copied from a.txt. After `git log -S"Hello world" -- a.txt` I find the orignal commit that introduced this into the codebase.

Is there a way to have one command that finds all those commits?

Note that a.txt has not been copied in its entirety, only `Hello world` was copied out. Similarly, not all of b.txt has been renamed to c.txt, only parts were moved there.

Comment: `git log -S"Hello world" -- '*.txt'`?